# javascript selection/range coordinates

Tags: javascript

I would like to absolute-position a div on either the initial or terminal corner of a text selection, as the user drags their mouse along. Unfortunately, Range only provides the index position, not the x/y coordinates. I think there might be a way to do this with range.insertNode, but only for one side. (This might also help someone position an auto-complete box under a contenteditable.)

How can I get the x/y coordinates of a text selection, or of the text cursor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works in chrome/webkit, positioning the div after the last-selected letter. Usually.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $div;
var last;
function find() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var text = selection.toString();
    if (last==text) return; else last=text; // prevent needless computations if no changes to selection
    if (selection.rangeCount==0) return;

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var $span= $("<span/>");

    newRange = document.createRange();
    newRange.setStart(selection.focusNode, range.endOffset);
    newRange.insertNode($span[0]); // using 'range' here instead of newRange unselects or causes flicker on chrome/webkit

    var x = $span.offset().left;
    var y = $span.offset().top;
    $div.text(x+" "+y);
    $div.css({left:x,top:y+($div.height())});
    $span.remove();
}
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        //find();
        setTimeout(find,0);
    });
    $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
        //find();
        setTimeout(find,0);
    });
    $div=$("<div style='border:1px solid red;background:white; position:absolute;'>").appendTo($("body"));
});
</script>
</head>
<body><p>the quick brown fox</p><ul><li>jumps <i>over</i></li></ul><p>the lazy dog</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get the mouse position from the mouse move event.  Then you can get the position of the text input element and do the math (make the mouse position relative).

EDIT:

[Here is a page](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptDownload/VSK-Form-Tools-Download-39681.html) where you can get JavaScript code that will get the caret position in pixels.

If you want to use JQuery, you can use [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/caretPosition)

Comment: This is incorrect, since you can move the text cursor using keyboard arrows (and change the selection, if you're holding shift).

Comment: Do you mean, then that you want to move the box based on the selection? whether they change the selection by mouse or by keys?

Comment: I mean you'll get very incorrect x/y positions, because mouse cursor position has nothing to do with text selection position. The question is clear on which I'm looking for. Select the words "Do you mean, then that you" with your mouse. Hold down shift. Now push the right arrow key. The selection has changed, but you are unaware. Now, select |this text|, and drag your mouse to the far left, and move it up and down. See how the selection changes?

Comment: The jQuery link is for textareas. The 'vsk' link returns undefined. It seems to be from http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/789061-caret-coordinates-pixels , which I saw already (by doing a search for the title of this post). It mentions there that it doesn't work in IE, and I've just confirmed that it doesn't work in webkit.