# How to determine the x/y screen coordinates of the last selected character on the page

Tags: javascript

I need to determine the x/y screen coordinates of the last selected character on the HTML page within a given DIV element (not in a textarea) so that I can pop up a message next to it. If found something similar here on StackOverflow with a [full example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/joktrpkz/7/)

Unfortunately that example places the text left-aligned to the last selected line and I need to put it at the end of the last selected line. Using getBoundingClientRect for the selected text doesn’t work when selecting multiple lines of text as when I try to right-align the popup it will always be at the very right of the screen.

```
sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
```

Is there a way using only JavaScript to find the x/y coordinates of the last selected character?

Comment: You just want it right aligned or at the very end of the line no matter what is highlighted?

Comment: Should be at the end of the last selected character, of the last selected line. So for example, If I start my selection in the middle of the first line of the paragraph, then select through the middle of the third line of the paragraph, I need to place the popup at the end of the selection on the third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the best way will be to insert the element into the DOM and let the browser worry about where on screen that is (at any particular moment).  The accepted answer at [javascript selection/range coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031518/javascript-selection-range-coordinates) works something like that.

(If you only want to affect some part of the screen, you should be able to filter based on the selection range's node information.)

The other concern I would have is, depending on user agent (especially where accessibility adaptations might be in play) it could be faulty to assume a selection change would correspond to a given input event.  You might want to look at the selection API and see if the events it defines are suitable to your purpose.

Comment: I looked at the link above for the accepted answer. I needed to tweak it a bit for my purposes, but I got it work as needed. Thanks Mark!