# Index of selected words using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selection

How can I get the index of selected text in HTML using Javascript?
For example, in an HTML file, there is paragraph like the following:

> I am living in India. India is the very beautiful country.

Now if the user selects `India` in the first sentence then there should be an `alert 5` and if the user selects `India` of second line then there is an `alert 6`.

How can I get the index of the word that the user selected?

Comment: Can you provide any example code that you written and doesn't work?
That way we could help you more easily

Also, counting the words before the one you are selecting isn't so hard to do once you get the selected content

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be done. well not easily that's for sure.

Comment: It is possible! Even if this other question don't give you the hole answer, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176761/get-selected-text-position

Comment: @gdoron: It can be done. http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/ArMHy/

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with the new [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) of my [Rangy library](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). Rangy's Range object has `moveStart()` and `moveEnd()` methods which allow you to expand the range a word at a time in either direction.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/ArMHy/

Code:

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    // Expand the range to contain the whole word
    range.expand("word");

    // Count all the preceding words in the document
    var precedingWordCount = 0;
    while (range.moveStart("word", -1)) {
        precedingWordCount++;
    }

    // Display results
    alert("Selection starts in word number " + (precedingWordCount + 1));        
}
```

Comment: hi tim down what library should I need to use this code in my iphone project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a string by its index, you can use-

```
string.match(regularExpression)[index]
```

Parameter Values-

**regularExpression** = Required. The value to search for, as a regular expression.

**index** = index of the regularExpression.

> Now you can consider this as an object and assign event handlers to it.