# How can I get the position number of selected text in the UIWebview of iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

Any one can help me how can I get the Position of selected text in web view of iPhone.
For Example :

God is great. We should pray God.

if user select  great then there is an alert saying 3rd word is selected . If user select pray then there is alert saying saying 6th word is selected.

Comment: I have googling but not got get any solution

Comment: @rishi: It might have been useful to provide a link to a duplicate question. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074017/index-of-selected-words-using-javascript/11075743#11075743