# How to get the word number of a word a user has selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble getting the word number of a word a user has selected

**For example**

I have a simple paragraph which contains two words Hi and bob

```
 <p>Hi bob</p>
```

So logically Hi=1 and bob=2. Now lets assume the user has selected bob I want the ***Program*** to log the number 2 to the console now lets assume the user has selected Hi it should log the number 1 to the console. Also this program should work for any amount of words.

**Any help would much appreciated**

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript

Comment: You can also have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074017/index-of-selected-words-using-javascript

Comment: Do you expect your text to be a mix of text and html tags?

Comment: What, if user selects both words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to pre-process, give each word a number first.
Then, make each word become "span" and assign events.

(in my example, i assumed that your "select" means "click" and used jQuery)

```js
  
    var container = $("#text");
    var words = container.text().split(" ");
    var count = 1;
    
    container.html("");
    
    words.forEach(function (word) {
        var span = $("<span></span>");
        span.data("number", count++);
        span.text(word + " ");
        span.click(function () {
            console.log($(this).data("number"))
        });
        container.append(span)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Hi bob hi bob hi bob</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer it worked on my end 

Answer (score -1):

You can split the words into an array, and use indexOf to get the index:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text").innerText.split(' ')
var userInput = prompt()
console.log(text.indexOf(userInput) + 1)
```

```html
<p id="text">Hi bob</p>
```

I added 1 since you wanted a human-readable version, if i left it without, it would think "hi" is the 0th word.

EDIT: Added prompt.

Comment: That's not what the author want.

Comment: @KévinBibollet How so? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: My bad, I misread the author post. I thought he was talking about mouse selection (by keeping the mouse button pressed).

Comment: @KévinBibollet No worries.