# Is it possible to get position of highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get X and Y position of the highlighted text by your mouse on the current active web page and if so how ?

Any links and advises how to achieve that with jQuery?

Comment: Do you have a specific scenario for needing it? (sorry just curious..)

Comment: This plugin does feature this : http://annotatorjs.org/

Comment: https://github.com/Phoenix404/SwipeDetector/blob/master/SwipeDetector.js

Answer (score 0):

You can check this Javascript library [rangeblock](https://github.com/lpimem/rangeblock).

You can locate, measure, and represent layouts of text ranges.

Example

```
// TypeScript
import * as rb from "rangeblock"

// measure layouts
let block = rb.extractSelectedBlock(window, document);
if (!block) {
    console.error("please select some text on the web page");
    return;
}
console.info("Text layout: " + JSON.stringify(block.dimensions));

// representation of the text range 
console.info("Text layout: " + JSON.stringify(block.rangeMeta));

// recreate range using RangeMeta
let meta :RangeMeta = ... ; 
block = rb.restoreBlock(window, document, meta);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need IE9:

> ```
> s = window.getSelection();
> ```
>
> Returns a Selection. So try
>
> ```
> s = window.getSelection();
> oRange = s.getRangeAt(0); //get the text range
> oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();
> ```
>
> oRect will be the bounding rectangle in client (fixed) coordinates.

[From this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887684/2334624).