# Get start and end Position of Highlighted text

Tags: javascript

I have referred [Getting selected text position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176761/getting-selected-text-position) and [Get selected text position and place an element next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/get-selected-text-position-and-place-an-element-next-to-it/1589912#1589912) but it's not working in my case.

My case is I want to get the start and end position of highlighted text and my code is

```
// TO GET THE HIGHLIGHTED TEXT VALUE
  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selectedTextValue = window.getSelection().toString()
    console.log(selectedTextValue)
  }
```

But when I use the below code then

```
// TO GET THE HIGHLIGHTED TEXT VALUE
  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selectedTextValue = window.getSelection().toString()
const oRange = selectedTextValue.getRangeAt(0); //get the text range: ;
const oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(oRect)
  }
```

I get the **error** Property 'getRangeAt' does not exist on type 'string'.

Where am I going wrong ? Please help !

Comment: ```.toString()``` converts your element to string and the error clearly states string doesn't have a function named ```getRangeAt``` i would recommend try without ```toString```

Comment: You need to call `getRangeAt()` at the result of `getSelection()`, not after converting it to a string. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt

Comment: But I want the highlighted text as string @pavankumar

Comment: @PeterB do you mean like this const selectedTextValue = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString()

Comment: You're trying to do two different things: do you want the selected text as a string, or do you want the position and bounds of the selection?

Comment: @skara I want both highlighted text as string and then start and end position of the highlighted text