# Get position from selected text in source HTML

Tags: javascript, html, textselection

How to get position from selected text in HTML?

the HTML content is rendered by setting innerHTML. For example `1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2` is rendered `1.   2`

The use is then selecting 2 with text selector.

```
const start = document.getSelection().anchorOffset
```

is working fine to get me the position in rendered text. Which is 5 is this case.

But is there some to get the position from HTML content (I think in this case it will be 20)

By the way [great article to learn selection](https://javascript.info/selection-range)

Comment: @Teemu i'm sorry, i didn't get it. what do you mean?

Comment: @Teemu you are right, i forgot ';' in my case they are there (will correct), but still don't know how to get the position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting selected text position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176761/getting-selected-text-position)

Comment: @jeremy-denis guess no, it is in a different context

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The problem is that the DOM doesn't know about entities. It doesn't know whether the HTML source originally contained the entity or the literal Unicode character.

However you probably don't need it. You shouldn't be working with the HTML source at this point, but with the content of the DOM. You'll need to show much more code and describe the much bigger picture.

Comment: i would like to perform split operation on an API.
The call is expecting an array of strings, but with HTML like it was before. This is the reason why i need this.

Comment: That is still not enough information. Why can't you take the text from the DOM instead of the original HTML?

Comment: backend api is expecting splitted HTML. If source HTML is '&nbsp;&nbsp; hello world' and i would like to split 'world' the api is expecting two stings '&nbsp;&nbsp; hello ' and 'world'

Comment: You would need match the original string to the DOM string.

Comment: this this exactly what is needed, do you have some ideas how this can be done? appreciated