# How can I find the Top position of an element next to user text selection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

from this topic:
[How can I position an element next to user text selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection/1589912#1589912)

i can get the left position from:

```
 var obj = arrow_btn;
            var left = top = 0;
            do {
                left += obj.offsetLeft;
                top += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

            console.log("left="+left);
            console.log("top=" + top);
```

but I get in the console:
left=590
top=[object DOMWindow]

any comments on why I can't get the Top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "top" is an immutable property of the global object "window" that refers to the top frame (DOMWindow). Your code is equivalent to:

```
var left;
window.top = 0; // no effect
left = window.top;
....
```

To correct it, just make sure top is a var;

```
var left = 0,
    top = 0;
```