# Inserting an element into a range clears the selection in Chrome

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I'm trying to insert a marker at the beginning of a selection (that I use to position an element atop the selection).

I'm running into a weird case in Chrome where the selection is cleared when the `range.insertNode` line is executed:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  var markerElement = document.createElement("span");
  markerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\ufeff"));
  // this will sometimes make the selection disappear in Chrome
  range.insertNode(markerElement);
  // make sure the marker is removed
  setTimeout(function(){
   markerElement.parentNode.removeChild(markerElement);
  }, 250);
});
```

Here is a `jsbin` example you can use to try it out: http://jsbin.com/agojib/1/edit

If you select a **single** letter, it will clear the selection.
Any other selection will be fine.

**Note:** I'm using a modification of the code provided in [How can I position an element next to user text selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it: http://jsbin.com/agojib/7/edit

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  // clone the current range
  var clone = range.cloneRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  var markerElement = document.createElement("span");
  markerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\ufeff"));
  // insert the marker in the first range
  range.insertNode(markerElement);
  // retrieve the selection
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  // remove all the ranges
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  // add the previously cloned range
  selection.addRange(clone);
  // make sure the marker is removed
  setTimeout(function(){
   markerElement.parentNode.removeChild(markerElement);
  }, 250);
});
```

The solution is basically to clone the range, insert the marker inside the first range and use the cloned range to reselect previously selected text.