# Highlighted text in a contenteditable div: Get the start and the end of the highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div contenteditable="true">This text is <b>Bold</b> not <i>Italic</i> right?</div>
```

For example if

> text is Bold not

is selected by the user, how do i know the exact position(offset) of the selection (highlight). I have read several articles about this but could not find one that explain.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution is probably to surround the selected text with an element and then get that elements position, see: [How can I position an element next to user text selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection/1589912#1589912)

Comment: Thanks. But I would have preferred to get the exact positions as stated above because of the logic I want to apply it with. Am working on a compose area of a site where user/client will simply click on the 'B' to get bold, 'I' for italic blah blah... just like in your ms-word application

Comment: So add the element (for example `<span>` ) with a reference counter or something and then apply the styles to it that the user clicks?