# Select text and add a tag to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a lot of question about this topic on SO but i can't seem to find any solution for my problem so i decide to ask my question. My situation is i have a dropdown list with several option and a textarea inside `iframe`. When user select some text in the textarea and choose one option from dropdown list then the selected text will have an `a` tag wrap around it and the option value will become tag `href`. Here my code:

```
   var optionTag       = document.getElementById("option-id");
   var optionValue     = optionTag.options[optionTag.selectedIndex].value;
   var iframe          = document.getElementById("my-frame");
   var iframeContent   = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML.split("<br>")[0];

    //get user selected text
   var iframeSelection = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection().toString();

    // and wrap a tag around it then add href equal to value of option
    var aTag        = "<a href=\"" + optionValue + "\">" + iframeSelection +"</a>";

   // replace user selected text with new a tag
   iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iframeContent.replace(iframeSelection,aTag)
```

This code **work** but it only replace the first word if that word already exist. For example:

```
lorem ipsum click dolor sit amet click spum
```

If user select the second word "click" and choose one option then my code will replace the only the first word "click" and if i have several word "click" it still only replace the first word, but if user select the word "ipsum" or "lorem" then it work fine. I don't know how to fix this please help. Thank!

**p/s:
I don't want to replace all the "click" word, i only want to replace exact piece user selected.**

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well, I'm having a hard time trying to understand the question.

Comment: Could you add HTML and, even better, setup fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry. i can't access the HTML code. For example i have 10 word "click" and i want to manually select each one then choose one option from the dropdown and the value from my option will become href attribute. But if i randomly choose one "click" word and choose one optioin then it's only wrap the first "click" that appear in my paragraph and add a tag plus href to that first word, not my current selected word. Sorry my english not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Javascript `String.replace()` only works like you expect when using it with a RegExp pattern with the global flag set. Luckily, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/1697755) has a nice solution.

Change this:

```
iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iframeContent.replace(iframeSelection,aTag);
```

...into this:

```
iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iframeContent.replace( new RegExp(iframeSelection, 'g'), aTag );
```

What it does is that it converts your search string into a RegExp object with the global flag set, so each occurrence gets replaced.

**If** your intention was to only replace the exact piece the user had selected it gets more complex, but you can find all the required bits from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589912/1697755).

Comment: Yes i only want to replace the exact piece the user selected. Please help :(

Comment: @Vk. I added another link to an answer that has what you're looking for

Comment: Thank a lot, i will try this as soon as i get to my work computer and let you know :D thank again @Schlaus

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `iframeSelection`  in your `replace()` call is "click", not the element you previously selected, so it's replacing the first occurence.

Instead, try getting the range of your selection, deleting it and appending your new element to that range.

```
var selection = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createElement(your_new_element));
```

I couldn't test without your HTML, a JSFiddle would help.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and let you know, thank alot @Drown :D