# Get bounding rectangle of selected text javascript

Tags: javascript

I use this code [How can I position an element next to user text selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection/1589912#1589912) to get the position of the selected text, but it doesn't work for the selected text inside an input. Sometimes the position is 0.

Is there some universal method for detecting the position of the selected text?

I want to show a tooltip on mouseup or dblclick the selected text.

Comment: If it's on mouseup/dblclick, can't you just use the position of the click event? Should just be `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle of your current code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the position of selected text:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var getRange = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
getRect = getRange.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: Is this solution cross-platform?

Comment: This works in Chrome, firefox and Safari for sure. I have not tested it with other browsers.

Comment: I does not work with Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: @AndrewFount https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-range It supposedly works in all modern browsers.

Comment: "It is worth noting that currently getSelection() doesn't work on the content of <textarea> and <input> elements in Firefox, Edge (Legacy) and Internet Explorer" - MDN

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) api.
After selection a text run below code in console.

```js
var selection = window.getSelection()
var baseOffset = selection.baseOffset
var length = selection.focusOffset -selection.baseOffset
var text = selection.focusNode.data.splice(baseOffset, length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to get the position where the user doubleclicked, use the following snippet.

```js
$('#thatInput').on('dblclick', function (e) {
  alert('Position X: ' + e.clientX + '\nPosition Y: ' + e.clientY);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="thatInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about getting the position of mouse pointer when selecting text. I am trying a solution that also works with keyboard events (choosed `keyup`).

I wrote a sample html page with a "vanilla" script inside to test the capabilities of the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection_API). This is the idea:

When selecting on text nodes, getting the position of selected text is done by means of the [Range Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

But when the selected text is a part of an `Input Element`, using the `getBoundingClientRect()` of the Range Object does not work (gave me a full zero `ClientRect Object`.

So, the function getSel() will try to consider both scenarios: selecting text just from the HTML or inside some input elements (just considered `input` and `textarea`).

On the bottom of the page there is a `div#results` element, for displaying data, then `getSel()` will create a new div#boundy with the coordinates of the ClientRect object or the related input element coordinates.

I wish to finish it, but I'm out of ideas on how to get the actual position of the selected text inside the input objects. It will have to be adding in a relative way to the coordinates of the element itself.

Answering Andrew, if this works, you'll be able to use the coordinates of div#boundy to place the tooltip wherever you want.

I've created a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/daniel-faure/pen/qYKPvY/?editors=0010).